# Subdomains and httpd

Tags: virtualhost, httpd, subdomain

I want to host 2 websites using httpd. I have the website panel.mcwownetwork.net and the website mcwownetwork.net. The problem is that connecting to mcwownetwork.net shows what panel.mcwownetwork.net show. While panel.mcwownetwork.net work as intended.

Here my files:

- httpd.conf: https://hastebin.com/zodemazinu.apache
- ssl.conf: https://hastebin.com/adeloxugiz.makefile

I'm using centos 6.8.

Comment: Please include the configuration files to the question, external links can become unavailable and then the question is worthless.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is answered at the bottom of your httpd.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ruben.oktay@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/panel/html/
    ServerName panel.mcwownetwork.net
</VirtualHost>
```

Make one of these for each of the domain names you want to host.